# MySQL Procedures for reporting total

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, procedures

Would anyone be able to help me with creating a procedure that reports the total amount paid in a specific month and specific year? Or how I would even go about creating this?

Thank you for any and all help.

Comment: Are you just trying to create a simple select statement? Or is there more to it?

Comment: What is your schema?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you have a table that includes both a date column as well as an amount paid column. If that is the case, and you just want to sum the amount paid you can just use the `SUM()` function.

Try this:

```
SELECT SUM(totalAmountPaid) as totalForMonth
FROM tableName
WHERE MONTH(dateColumn) = monthYouWant AND YEAR(dateColumn) = yearYouWant
```

Here are [date and time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) that may be useful.